# Getting System.Net.ConnectStream. asp.net(visual basic)

Tags: asp.net

I'm a newbie ^^
I am working an a project for my dissertation, I have to generate a QR code from some data in my db. That is actually my second concern my first is

- I used this code to ENCODE a QR code

**codebehind

```
Imports Esponce.QRCode
Imports System.IO

Partial Class QR
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

  Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim client = New QRCodeClient()
    Dim stream = client.Generate("Hello World")

    Literal1.Text = stream.ToString


  End Sub
End Class
```

It debugs then only displays:  System.Net.ConnectStream when the button is clicked :(

Can I get some help to get to know about how to actually view the QR code generated?

Thanking you guys ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Your QR code will be an image, so you cant really display it in the textbox, unless you want the BASE64 encoded binary value.

You should be able to do:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
img.Save(Server.MapPath("/images/img.png"));
```

Add Image control to the page name it "myImage"

```
myImage.ImageUrl = "/images/img.png";
```

You will need "write" permissions for the images directory

Edit: if the QRCodeClient generates jpeg or gif, change extension.